# Detect PC and redirect code help needed

Tags: php, browser-detection

The following code detects a PC browser and it redirects.
It is a working one.
But , I want someone's help to change it to display something.

```
  <?

$webversion = "http://www.webversion.com";

$agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (preg_match("/window/i", $agent)) {
header( "Location: $webversion" ) ;
}

if (preg_match("/mac/i", $agent)) {
header( "Location: $webversion" ) ;
}

if (preg_match("/microsoft/i", $agent)) {
header( "Location: $webversion" ) ;
}

if (preg_match("/linux/i", $agent)) {
header( "Location: $webversion" ) ;
}
?>
```

I want it like

```
if(usingPC)
echo 'something';
else
echo 'somethingelse'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would create a function to encapsulate the test that you have above

```
function usingPC(){
      return preg_match("/window/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

To use this you would have to adapt your code to be:

```
if(usingPC())
    echo 'something';
else
    echo 'somethingelse'
```

Comment: How to include "/mac/i", "/microsoft/i" and "/linux/i" in it ?